# quiero cambiar el color de un "value" de una input usando css

Tags: php, css

Creé una pequeña tabla para realizar un formulario.
La tabla contiene:

```
               Nombre: (casilla para agregar nombre)
               Teléfono: (+598 casilla para agregar número)
```

Como ven, en "teléfono" hay un número prescrito  (hecho con value).
Lo que yo quiero es agregar un color específico a ese "+598" (ej: color rojo) y que al escribir los números restantes, estos, tengan otro color (ej:negro) y además que no se pueda borrar el "+598" (manteniendo el +598 dentro de la casilla claro).

Quedaría algo así lo que quiero:

```
                       Nombre: ( Juan Pepe)
                       Teléfono (+598 5454545554)
```

(con el +598 en rojo y sin poder borrarse y los otros números en negro)
 Gracias de antemano

Probé mil formas distintas de cambiarlo usando css y ninguna funcionó.

Busqué en Internet y nada, ando bastante estresado.

`<div id="Contenido">`

`<fieldset id="Disco2">`

`<legend>Insertar</legend>`

```
 `<form id="Datos" action="Insertado.php" method="post">`

   `<table>`
```

`<tr>`

```
  `<td>Nombre:</td>`
  `<td><input id="datanom" name="nom" type="text"></td>`
```

`</tr>`

`<tr>`

```
  `<td>Teléfono:</td>`
  `<td><input id="datatel" name="tel" type="text" value="+598"></td>`
```

`</tr>`

CSS

`input#datatel[value=+598] {`

`color:red;`

`}`

Comment: Nos muestras por favor el HTML donde esta contenido dicho valor?

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y ahi coloca el texto, desde la zona de comentarios se hace difícil leerlo

Comment: además te recomendaría agregar lo que has intentado, aunque tenga errores

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, disculpá el inconveniente jaja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Emulando Campo `<input>` con un poco de CSS

Como ya han mencionado no se puede aplicar dos estilos de color al valor de un `<input>` sin embargo con un poco de imaginación podemos emular un campo `<input>` con las características planteadas por el OP.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo muy sencillo de como se puede hacer

```css
#code {
background-color:white;
color:red;
border-style: groove none groove groove;
width:36px
}
#phone {
border-style: groove groove groove none;
}
```

```html
Nombre: <input id="name"><br><br>
Telefono: <input id="code" value="+958" disabled><input id="phone">
```

Comment: Es EXACTAMENTE lo que buscaba. Te agradezco un montón, saludos.

Comment: me alegra saber que mi respuesta te ayudo y recuerda calificar la pregunta que mas se ajuste a la solución del problema, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

[En su respuesta, Jon Cram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121683/is-there-a-way-to-style-part-of-an-input-fields-value) explica que lo que necesitas no se puede hacer con html y css, básicamente porque el estilo css aplica a todo el contenido del input.

Sin embargo, se me ocurre desplegar el contenido preescrito en un elemento html no editable, como un elemento  al cual podemos estilizar para que parezca un input

Ejemplifico:

```css
#datatel {
    border : none;
    border-bottom : 1px solid #2b2b2b;
}

#preescrito {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #2b2b2b;
    padding : 0.02em;
    color    : #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="Contenido">
    <fieldset id="Disco2">
        <legend>Insertar</legend>
        <form id="Datos" action="Insertado.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <!---Nombre-------------->
                <tr>
                    <td>Nombre:</td>
                    <td><input id="datanom" name="nom" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <!---Número-------------->
                <tr>
                    <td>Teléfono:</td>
                    <td><label id ="preescrito" for input="datatel">+958</label><input id="datatel" name="tel" type="text" value=""></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

¡Cuidado! si te fijas, le he dado en el ejemplo un padding de 0.02em a label#preescrito para que el borde cuadre con el del input#dataset. En tu código, esto podría requerir mas trabajo e investigación según el estilo que hayas dado a los elementos de tu formulario.

¡Mucha suerte!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te coloco una posible solucion al problema,

**Primero:** En css no se puede colocar dos colores diferentes en un un input por lo tanto hay que hacer otro recurso como el solapar dos etiquetas span que esten dentro del bloque compartiendo el mismo espacio y una tomara el valor del prefijo y la otra el numero.

Este es el codigo con el cual puede ver el prefijo de un color y el numero con otro.

```js
          $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
              valor = $(this).val();
              fin = $(this).val().length;
              if (fin > 3) {
                // para poner numero
                 $('.prefix').html('+' + valor.substr(0,3) + '<span class="numero">' + valor.substr(3,fin) +'</span>' ); 
              } else {
                 // solo el prefijo
                 $('.prefix').html('+' + valor);
              }
              // limpiar contenido 
              if (fin==0) {
                $('.prefix').empty();
              }
           });
```

```css
            label {
                    position: relative;
                }


                label input[type="text"] {
                    position: relative;
                }

                .prefix {
                    color: red;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 5px;
                    top: 1px;
                    z-index: 100;
                }

                .numero {
                    color: gray;
                    margin-left: 5px;
                    position: relative;
                    z-index: 1000;
                }

                input[type="text"] {
                    color: transparent;
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <h1>Texto</h1>
    <label><span class="prefix"></span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" />
    </label>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el CSS, se coloco al input en color trasparente y los span solapan dentro del input

El codigo Jquery captura el evento del teclado y va agregando el valor correspondiente deacuerdo al rango (1-3) es el codigo el cual se coloca en el `span` de clase .prefix, ya cuando el valor pasa de 4 en adelante se crea una construccion donde se agrega otro span para los numeros con la clase .numero.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, saludos.