# Bloquear dia en input de tipo date

Tags: html, css, date

Tengo el siguiente input de tipo `date`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha" value="2019-02-01">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Mi duda es saber si existe alguna manera de poder **bloquear el día** de manera tal que el usuario no pueda modificarla. Algo así como un `disabled`.

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien la pregunta, ¿lo que quieres es que solo pueda modificar el mes y el año en el input? ¿podrías agregar mas información?

Comment: Si lo que buscas es que solo se vea el mes y el año en el input puedes revisar  [Mostrar solo mes y año en un input de tipo fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/284826/mostrar-solo-mes-y-a%c3%b1o-en-un-input-de-tipo-fecha/284827#284827)

Comment: Hola @the-breaker, si, pero solo deshabilitar el dia, que el usuario no pueda modificarlo

Comment: @Hugo Con un `input` común y corriente no puedes. Debes usar algún plugin javascript

Answer (score 1):

Una forma posible puede ser emularlo con 2 inputs, uno deshabilitado con el día fijo y el otro puede ser input de tipo month, luego se agrega código css para dar estilo a los inputs y que luzcan como uno solo:

```css
#dia {
font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace; font-size: 14px;
background-color:white;
border-style: groove none groove groove;
width:43px
}
#fecha {
border-style: groove groove groove none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="dia" value="01 de  " disabled><input type="month" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha" value="2019-02-01" onchange="console.log(this.value+'-01')" >
    </body>
    </html>
```

Se debe tomar el cuenta que debe agregarse el valor del día al obtener el valor del input ya que debería estar deshabilitado, también que el input type month aun no es compatible con Firefox, IE y Safari.

Espero haber aportado a resolver el problema, saludos.

**Referencias:**

[Emulando Campo  con un poco de CSS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/287400/77879)

[Mostrar solo mes y año en un input de tipo fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/284826/mostrar-solo-mes-y-a%C3%B1o-en-un-input-de-tipo-fecha?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[input type="month"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month)

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero utilizar DateTime Picker, puedes deshabilitar días de la semana en especifico, entre otras cosas:

```
daysOfWeekDisabled: "1,2,3,4,5",
```